# Why does this function that uses a scoped type variable in a where clause not typecheck?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a function that has a value defined in a `where` clause, and I want to give it an explicit type annotation. The annotation needs to use a type variable from the top-level function, so it was my understanding that I needed to use `ScopedTypeVariables`. Here is a minimal reduction of the problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Data.Functor.Identity

f :: ExceptT String Identity a -> Maybe a
f m = Nothing
  where x :: Identity (Either String a)
        x = runExceptT m
```

This code does *not* typecheck. It fails with the following error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for f :: ExceptT String Identity a -> Maybe a
      at src/Lib.hs:20:6
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for x :: Identity (Either String a1)
       at src/Lib.hs:22:14
Expected type: ExceptT String Identity a1
  Actual type: ExceptT String Identity a
Relevant bindings include
  x :: Identity (Either String a1) (bound at src/Lib.hs:23:9)
  m :: ExceptT String Identity a (bound at src/Lib.hs:21:3)
  f :: ExceptT String Identity a -> Maybe a
    (bound at src/Lib.hs:21:1)
In the first argument of ‘runExceptT’, namely ‘m’
In the expression: runExceptT m
```

Why does this fail? I do not understand why this would cause problems—it seems like a textbook use of scoped type variables. For reference, I am using GHC 7.10.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an [explicit forall](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#lexically-scoped-type-variables):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Data.Functor.Identity

f :: forall a. ExceptT String Identity a -> Maybe a
f m = Nothing
  where x :: Identity (Either String a)
        x = runExceptT m
```

### *but why*

That is a great question. This appears to be a rule of `ScopedTypeVariables`. We know in GHC Haskell that all top-level variables are implicitly `forall`'d, as documented [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#decl-type-sigs). One would suspect that the GHC devs added this behavior for backwards compatibility: without this rule, a file without the extension turned on could stop type-checking once the extension was turned on. We can easily imagine a scenario where helper functions declared in the `where` block to inadvertently reuse the common type variable names `a, b, c, t`, so on. It would be great if someone could find the exact spot in the GHC source code where this distinction between explicit and implicit `forall`'d variables arose.

### *update*

Here we go (although this is all guesswork from the comments and grepping):

- While type-checking user signatures, the function `tcUserTypeSig` invokes `findScopedTyVars`. [TcBinds.hs:ef44606:L1786](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ef44606/compiler/typecheck/TcBinds.hs#L1786)
- `findScopedTyVars` in `TcRnTypes` filters for `forall`s by calling `tcSplitForAllTys`. [TcRnTypes.hs:ef44606:L1221](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ef44606692e731c9be45df5ee6819e0912f37a58/compiler/typecheck/TcRnTypes.hs#L1221)
- Which is a wrapper around `splitForAllTys`, which folds over a type's subtypes to build up a list of type variables introduced by `forall`s. [Types/Type.hs:ef44606:L1361](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ef44606692e731c9be45df5ee6819e0912f37a58/compiler/types/Type.hs#L1361)

Comment: Huh. Could you explain *why* I need that here? The docs just seem to imply that type variables are not brought in scope unless you use `forall`; is that correct?

Comment: @AlexisKing Correct. The default is to preserve the without-extensions behaviour, so that old code (without explicit foralls) will not suddenly stop working because an extension was turned on.

Comment: @chi is correct. The result is that this is very much a "gotcha" situation—the behavior that @AlexisKing expects is the way it ideally should work. (Actually, given how often I have to turn it on, I'd say that `ScopedTypeVariables` should have been the default, not an extension!)

Comment: @LuisCasillas I totally agree. The original Haskell definition got this wrong IMHO, and now changing the default could break old code. (Albeit I do wonder how much code would be broken... It would not be the first time GHC breaks retro-compatibility for the greater good)

Comment: I've seen code break when `ScopedTypeVariables` is turned on because it also brings variables in instance heads into scope in their bodies. Personally, I'd still like to see it in the standard, and I know that at least one member of the new language committee agrees.