# Seemingly correct type signature refused in where block

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have been messing around with continuation passing style in Haskell. Taking the `Cont` monad apart and removing the type wrappers helped me in understanding the implementation. Here is the code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad (ap)


newtype Cont r a = Cont {runCont :: (a -> r) -> r}

instance Functor (Cont r) where
  fmap f ka = ka >>= pure . f

instance Applicative (Cont r) where
  (<*>) = ap
  pure = return

instance Monad (Cont r) where

  ka >>= kab = Cont kb'
    where
      -- kb' :: (b -> r) -> r
      kb' hb = ka' ha
        where
          -- ha :: (a -> r)
          ha a = (kab' a) hb

      -- ka' :: (a -> r) -> r
      ka' = runCont ka

      -- kab' :: a -> (b -> r) -> r
      kab' a = runCont (kab a)


  return a = Cont ka'
    where
      -- ka' :: (a -> r) -> r
      ka' ha = ha a
```

This code compiles (using GHC 8.0.2) and everything seems fine. However, as soon as I uncomment any of the (now commented) type signatures in the where block I get an error. For exapmle, if I uncomment the line

```hs
      -- ka' :: (a -> r) -> r
```

I get:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a b. Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
        at cont.hs:19:6
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          ka' :: forall a1. (a1 -> r) -> r
        at cont.hs:27:14
      Expected type: (a1 -> r) -> r
        Actual type: (a -> r) -> r
    • In the expression: runCont ka
      In an equation for ‘ka'’: ka' = runCont ka
      In an equation for ‘>>=’:
          ka >>= kab
            = Cont kb'
            where
                kb' hb
                  = ka' ha
                  where
                      ha a = (kab' a) hb
                ka' :: (a -> r) -> r
                ka' = runCont ka
                kab' a = runCont (kab a)
    • Relevant bindings include
        ka' :: (a1 -> r) -> r (bound at cont.hs:28:7)
        kab' :: a -> (b -> r) -> r (bound at cont.hs:31:7)
        kab :: a -> Cont r b (bound at cont.hs:19:10)
        ka :: Cont r a (bound at cont.hs:19:3)
        (>>=) :: Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
          (bound at cont.hs:19:3)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So I tried using a type wildcard to let the compiler tell me what type signature I should put there. As such I tried the following signature:

```hs
      ka' :: _
```

Which gave the following error:

```
    • Found type wildcard ‘_’ standing for ‘(a -> r) -> r’
      Where: ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the instance declaration at cont.hs:15:10
             ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 (>>=) :: forall a b. Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
               at cont.hs:19:6
      To use the inferred type, enable PartialTypeSignatures
    • In the type signature:
        ka' :: _
      In an equation for ‘>>=’:
          ka >>= kab
            = Cont kb'
            where
                kb' hb
                  = ka' ha
                  where
                      ha a = (kab' a) hb
                ka' :: _
                ka' = runCont ka
                kab' a = runCont (kab a)
      In the instance declaration for ‘Monad (Cont r)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        ka' :: (a -> r) -> r (bound at cont.hs:28:7)
        kab' :: a -> (b -> r) -> r (bound at cont.hs:31:7)
        kab :: a -> Cont r b (bound at cont.hs:19:10)
        ka :: Cont r a (bound at cont.hs:19:3)
        (>>=) :: Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
          (bound at cont.hs:19:3)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Now I am really confused, the compiler tells me the type of `ka'` is `(a -> r) -> r` but as soon as I try to explicitely annotate `ka'` with this type,
compiling fails. First I thought I was missing `ScopedTypeVariables` but it does not seem to make a difference.

What is going on here?

**EDIT**
This is similar to the question " [Why does this function that uses a scoped type variable in a where clause not typecheck?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36989329/2496293) " in that it requires an explicit `forall` to bind type variables. However it is not a duplicate since the answer to this question also requires the `InstanceSigs` extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this function that uses a scoped type variable in a where clause not typecheck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989329/why-does-this-function-that-uses-a-scoped-type-variable-in-a-where-clause-not-ty)

Comment: On second glance, maybe not an exact duplicate, but related. You need to bring `a` into scope using a `forall` somewhere, but since this is an instance method, I think you also need `InstanceSigs`.

Comment: You're on the right track with `ScopedTypeVariables` (which puts `r` in scope in the instance), but you need to bind `a` also with `InstanceSigs` extension, giving the signature for `(>>=)`.  You could also avoid the extension by giving `(>>=) = bind` and then providing a signature for `bind` in a `where` clause.  But I rather like `InstanceSigs` and am not sure why they are not normally allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes sense. After all, where did those `a`s and `b`s come from? We have no way to know they're connected to the polymorphism of `(>>=)` and `return`. It's easy to fix, though, as mentioned in the comments: give `(>>=)` and `return` type signatures that mention `a` and `b`, toss in the requisite language extension, and hey presto:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

import Control.Monad (ap)


newtype Cont r a = Cont {runCont :: (a -> r) -> r}

instance Functor (Cont r) where
  fmap f ka = ka >>= pure . f

instance Applicative (Cont r) where
  (<*>) = ap
  pure = return

instance Monad (Cont r) where

  (>>=) :: forall a b. Cont r a -> (a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r b
  ka >>= kab = Cont kb'
    where
      kb' :: (b -> r) -> r
      kb' hb = ka' ha
        where
          ha :: (a -> r)
          ha a = (kab' a) hb

      ka' :: (a -> r) -> r
      ka' = runCont ka

      kab' :: a -> (b -> r) -> r
      kab' a = runCont (kab a)


  return :: forall a. a -> Cont r a
  return a = Cont ka'
    where
      ka' :: (a -> r) -> r
      ka' ha = ha a
```

I feel like there's a Dragonball joke in all these `ka`s and `ha`s, but the joke escapes `me`.

Comment: Yep, this compiles and totally makes sense. I didn't know about `InstanceSigs` but it's a really useful extenstion in my opinion. It makes intance declerations clearer too if you don't remember the exact type signature of the function being implemented. There is no Dragonball joke however :)

Comment: @SamDeMeyer I didn't know about the extension before today, either! Turns out if you toss in the type signatures, GHC helpfully says "Illegal type signature in instance declaration (Use InstanceSigs to allow this)".