# How can I specify the polymorphic type of a sub-expression?

Tags: haskell

This compiles:

```
foo :: (Bounded a,Enum a) => a -> Int
foo x = length ([minBound .. x] ++ drop 1 [x .. maxBound])
```

This doesn't compile:

```
foo :: (Bounded a,Enum a) => a -> Int
foo x = length ([minBound .. maxBound] :: [a])
```

I think the second example doesn't compile because the type `a` in the type signature is not the same as the one in the sub-expression's type signature. How can I make the sub-expression's type refer to the polymorphic type given above?

Comment: I think you're looking for the ScopedTypeVariables extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the purpose of [the `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#lexically-scoped-type-variables). You need to do two things:

1. Enable [the `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#lexically-scoped-type-variables), probably by adding `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to the top of your file.
2. Bring the type variables into scope in `foo`’s type signature using `forall`.<sup>†</sup>

After making both of those changes, you should end up with this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

foo :: forall a. (Bounded a, Enum a) => a -> Int
foo _ = length ([minBound .. maxBound] :: [a])
```

This should compile successfully.

---

<sup>† For information on why this is necessary, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989449/465378).</sup>

Comment: Or `[minBound .. maxBound :: a]`